# Apache Mesos for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, mesos, mesosphere

How to run apache mesos on raspberry pi 3? Shoul I build it by myself or there is any packages for raspbian? I can not find any fresh tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Currently, it's not possible to build whole Mesos Cluster on Raspberry PI. You can only run Mesos Agent.**

You should build your own packages following steps described in [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#ubuntu-1404) It might not work. I know there were some issues with compiling dependencies so you might need to use older Mesos version.

```
apt-get install -y tar wget git
apt-get install -y autoconf libtool
apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev python-boto libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules maven libapr1-dev libsvn-dev
cd ~/mesos
./bootstrap
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --disable-python --disable-java
make
```

I created a proposal for ARM support for Mesos. It's available [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Hs40tGSUyoQa78ifVvn7VO5iSqe8nMc7VYWSugOqGFw/edit?usp=sharing).

[Here](http://blog.haosdent.me/2016/04/24/mesos-on-arm/index.html) is a brilliant tutorial how to do it compiling on QEMU but as you noticed it's not fresh.

You can ask someone to share their ARM packages [See this message](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/0ed9c7e375cacbb05c7688cfc9983d15b6d7a0f4b95aa5c37e2885cc@%3Cuser.mesos.apache.org%3E)